# Why are my Laravel migrations (MySQL) so much faster in MacOS?

Tags: mysql, performance

This is not so much of a problem as it's mostly just up to some hundreds of milliseconds of difference per migration; but I could not understand why my desktop [Windows 11] with I7-13700K, 64GB RAM, and Samsung 980 Pro [2TB] with 1.5TB free is slower than my MacBook Pro 2019 with I9-9980HK, 64GB RAM, 512GB SSD whenever I run migrations.

There are instances where I prefer to just re-run my migrations and seeders when debugging new projects, especially when I just want to clean up my test data and redo some testing. I just can't help but notice that it's so much faster to re-run my migrations when I work on my Mac even when my desktop should be so much faster.

Both machines are under the same network (which may not matter as migrations are run to localhost db), and there is no load/stress on both systems when I tested to see their difference.

Migration from my Windows 11 Machine
[image: WIN-11-Migrations]

Migration from my MacOS Machine
[image: MAC-OS-Migrations]

I have already tried disabling the firewall, windows defender, and even increasing the mysql innodb pool size config; but nothing seems to make it faster. I even tried installing Ubuntu via WSL2 and setup MySQL  in Ubuntu, but I still get pretty much the same performance.

The only difference between the two is the MySQL Version:

-- 8.0.33 on Mac

-- 8.0.36 on Windows

Any ideas on how I can improve the performance on my Windows Machine? Or is it something I just have to deal with because of the differences on how the OS handles things?

EDIT [02/20/24]
So I decided to install VMWare [Ubuntu 22.04] and install MySQL server in the VM instead [Specced to use 4 cores, 16GB RAM and 64GB Storage). Changed the MySQL config (bind-address) so that I could connect to it from my Native OS [Windows]; and voila. I am now getting faster if not equivalent speed in comparison to my Mac OS machine. So the performance issue I have has to do with MySQL in Windows, since it works fast in my VM out of the box. Note that my MySQL installation in Windows should also be using default configs. I only touched it because it was slow, in attempt to improve its performance.

Screenshot below on the latency/performance of my migrations using the MySQL in VM.
[image]

Comment: MySQL in windows is running in docker or native?

Comment: Hi @DanielCosta, this is native. It could be that MySQL server is just slower in Windows than it is on other OS. What I tried was install a VM and install MySQL server in it. I am now getting faster or equivalent performance compared to my Mac; using the MySQL server I installed in my VM.